# Failed SendKey command vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I'm new to vbscript, and this is one of my first scripts. What I'm trying to do is to automate opening PDF file in chrome, copying its content and pasting it to a new .txt file.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'opening the pdf file (path stored in the 'path' variable)
objShell.Run """C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"" """ & path & """"
'waiting for chrome to open
WScript.Sleep 6000

'sending ctrl+a & ctrl+c to copy all the text
objShell.SendKeys "^a"
objShell.SendKeys "^c" 

'creating a new text file, path stored in the 'NewFile' variable
objFSO.CreateTextFile NewFile,True

'opening the new file with notepad 
objShell.run """C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe"" """ & NewFile & """"

'waiting for notepad to open
WScript.Sleep 5000

'sending ctrl+a, ctrl+v and ctrl+s to paste and save
objShell.SendKeys "^a"
objShell.SendKeys "^v"
objShell.SendKeys "^s"
```

But for some reason, the file contains whatever I copied before - the ^c didn't work, although the ^s did (I can see that the text is selected). I tried it with shift+F10, without seeing any improvement, even though when I try to do it manually it's working perfectly.

I don't have to copy the PDF through chrome, but working with adobe handlers is not an option for me.

I would be thankful for any help!

Comment: Try using Internet Explorer instead of chrome.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but internet explorer doesn't support the ^a shortcut, so it is not fit for my need...

Comment: I just tried your code, changing chrome to IE (version:8. that's the only version I have) and it seemed to work. Doesn't `^a` work for you if you try manually ?